# Angular2 Import self invoked jQuery library from query.selectareas.js give Runtime Error : jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, self-invoking-function

I have strange problem here with **self invoked function** which need **jquery** .

This is the library i want to use : [jquery.selectareas.js](https://github.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas/blob/master/jquery.selectareas.js)

This is the code

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import  "query.selectareas.js"
```

> Runtime Error :  jQuery is not defined  [at this line](https://github.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas/blob/master/jquery.selectareas.js#L861)

I tried to import JQ with all different combinations

```
//import * as $ from 'jquery';
//import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
//window['$'] = window['jQuery'] = $;
//import  "jquery"
```

What I understand that the imported **jQuery** should be available  inside the [jquery.selectareas.js](https://github.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas/blob/master/jquery.selectareas.js) scope when importing it, because they will be inside same scope .

*Note : **jquery** work i used it after all import statements*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need [imports-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader)

```
import  "imports-loader?jQuery=jquery!query.selectareas.js"
```

This will inject a `jQuery` variable to your imported module